# How to implement bottomsheet like gmail profile view

Tags: android, android-support-design, bottom-sheet

Beautifully implemented bottom sheet with animation in Gmail v6.5,Google Maps and Facebook comment view.
I like to implement same for my app so that I present detail using bottomsheets that merge with actionbar and swipe down to dismiss to easy navigation.
Like one with cross button on toolbar discuss in [material design guidelines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xG8cV.png)

I follow [this][2] tutorial using `BottomSheetDialogFragment` but it shows up half and can't expend to full height. I haven't get any good result.

Gmail User Profile View (Peeking and Expended)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create it using these library's

[**Lib 1**](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet)
[**Lib 2**](https://github.com/soarcn/BottomSheet)

Comment: I have tried first one. I want to implement with only design lib

Comment: dear you have to customize it with your design.

Comment: @Qamar I hope you successfully completed the target. Could you please share the way which you followed to do this ?

Comment: At that time Lib 1 but @Kamalone you can do this using only BottomSheetFragment from google:design with adding fragment transition animation to common views and scroll listeners